# Inserting value into database using curl

Tags: php

This is my **index.php** file

```
<?php
   $data = array("name"=>"ohidul","age"=>25);
   $string = http_build_query($data);
   $ch = curl_init("http://localhost/curl/send_data_to_server/data.php");
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,true);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$string);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
   curl_exec($ch);
   curl_close($ch);
?>
```

This is my **data.php** file

```
<?php 
   if(isset($_POST['name'],$_POST['age'])){
      $db = new Mysql('localhost','root','','postdata');
      $name = $db->real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
      $age = (int) $_POST['age'];
      $query = "INSET INTO data SET mydata='$name,$age'";
      $db->query($query);
   }
?>
```

Here I want to store the value of `index.ph`p into the database. I am using `curl` method of `php`. But the values are not insert into the database.

**How** to fix this?

Comment: your insert method is wrong

Comment: Your query should be $query = "INSERT INTO data (name, age) values ('$name','$age')";

Comment: what's your `data` table schema?

Comment: and you have a typo in your insertion query, it's `INSERT` instead of `INSET`

Comment: it works.thank u.problem was INSET.

Answer (score 0):

Your usage of query is wrong. It should be like this.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO data(name, age) VALUES ('$name','$age')";
```

You may want to consider using parameters instead of simply putting the variables to query to prevent SQL Injection.

Comment: does the fields wrong? can you tell me the right fields because there is no way I can know the fields?

Comment: @david the original query syntax is applicable too, regardless the typo in the INSET word

Comment: No fields are right.my database name is postdata,table name data and field name is mydata.but there is question.you insert the value into data table.but i insert the value into mydata field which is a field in data table.both are same?

Comment: do you mean you want to put both name and age in the same field?

Comment: Yes.I declare the field as text field.It works now.thank u.

Comment: if my query really works for you, you may want to consider accepting this answer to help others who have similar problem in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I guess problem is with the way you are trying to post data, you dont need to do  http_build_query() instead you need to pass array with CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS option.

see below code:

```
<?php
   $data = array("name"=>"ohidul","age"=>25);
   $ch = curl_init("http://localhost/curl/send_data_to_server/data.php");
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,true);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
   curl_exec($ch);
   curl_close($ch);
?>
```